# Time series behavior based on previous data

Tags: time-series

Apologies in advance for incorrect use of terminology - I do not have much of a background in statistics.

Suppose I have the following behavior for daily stock returns:

When $r_{i+1} > r_i$, then $r_{i+2} < r_{i+1}$ with probability $>50$%. Conversely, when $r_{i+1} < r_i$, then $r_{i+2} > r_{i+1}$ with probability $>50$%.

Describe what is happening/define this phenomenon, and explain how one can profit from knowing this information.

My knowledge/intuition in dealing with time-series is limited, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also known as "please answer my homework"? If so, please tag it as such. Oh, and look into autoregressive trends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is effectively predict the sign of the equity returns using lagged signs. You'll probably need to learn a lot about time series to do this well. One approach would be to create an indicator $x_{t}=0$ if $r_{t}-r_{t-1}<0$ and $x_{t}=1$ if $r_{t}-r_{t-1}>0$, then estimate a probit model, which should be standard in most statistical packages, and use that for prediction. A simple, obvious trading strategy to backtest would be to invest in the security if the model predicts the sign to be positive and invest in cash otherwise.

There are also machine learning algorithms that can deal with these sorts of problems, but may require a bit of a time investment to undestand. There is also a significant literature on regime-switching in equity markets. Markov regime switching would attempt to model the mean expected return in $k$ states. Each state would have a probability that you are in it and overall dynamics that drive the behavior of the state probabilities. This is not standard in most statistical packages, but there are implementations available.

Comment: Thanks! When, if at all, would this ever happen in an economy?

Comment: I assume this is homework then? This process exhibits mean-reversion, which you can model with an AR(p) model in (log) levels. Since it is not a random walk, you could not say the market is efficient. It is possible that the market is over-reacting to news and then correcting.